# MongoDB - how to search fields with different data types?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to search multiple fields in a document. Each of these fields could be of type `Date`, `String` or `Number`. I have tried using an `$or` query using a Regex to search for a search term, but it will only search within the field that are of type `String`:

```
SomeCollection.find({
    $or: [
        {sometext:   /searchterm/},
        {somedate:   /searchterm/},
        {somenumber: /searchterm/}
    ]
});
```

Is it posisble to search across fields with different data types?

Comment: regex only works for strings but `$or` can work across types.

Comment: @MichelFloyd - so how do I check if `searchterm` is contained within a number or a date?

Comment: Convert it to both a number and a date and use it in your search. Since you are doing an `$or` search you'll generally be ok. You might want to weed out some values however (like NaN).

Comment: You might also want to use momentJS to convert free form text dates to actual dates.

Comment: What if the search term is not a date or a number - will the conversion cause the conversion to result in NaN and, if so, how is this handled within the $or clause?

Comment: I don't think it hurts to search a date field for a NaN in the middle of an $or - it just won't match anything on date. But if you know that the search string converts to NaN then why include that clause in the $or? It will slow down the search.

Comment: Take the scenario where some types '16' into the search field and I have a result in the database where the date field contains 01/01/2016 - i need to return this result, so how to do his?

Comment: For that you'd want to have a text version of the date in the db as well and search that (but in what format?). You're getting yourself into a lot of complication in a hurry though, especially with dates.